# How to detect and handle NSIS compile-time errors?

Tags: compiler-errors, nsis

I'm working with NSIS 2.46 to build some installers.  As part of the installer build process, I need to use `!system` to run some commands (in this case, some Python/pip commands, although that's not important).  I'd like to be able to handle situations where `!system` returns a non-zero value (probably, by just using `!error` to display a message and exit, although again, that's not important).

How can I access the return value from `!system`, to check for errors?

I've looked at the documentation, and searched both here and elsewhere, but not yet found any answers.

Comment: v2.46 is old, you should at least upgrade to v2.50.

Comment: When you said you looked at the documentation, did you actually look at the documentation for !system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NSIS [v2](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#system) all you can do is `!system '"whatever" /whatever' = 0` and the compiler will abort if the exit code is not 0.

In v3 it is also possible to save the exit code in a define:

```
!system '"whatever" /whatever' code
!if ${code} > 666
!error "Ooops"
!endif
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I think I must have misunderstood what that was saying in the documentation, the first time I read it.